# how to watch / convert cctv footage with apparently no extension on it?

Tags: video, cctv

someone brought me a footage from a cctv (regarding some minor robbery) and is asking me to show him the thief,
all I have is a ~1 GB file with no extension, and a windows software (apparently came from cctv) for watching the videos from pc named " processviewr7 "

I can't open the file with this software because there is no extension on file, and I have tried some common extensions but had no luck,
what should I do?

Comment: Did you try dragging the file into the software?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't recognizes the file

Comment: Which Operating System (OS) are you using? If you are on a *Nix, the command: file filename   will automatically identify the appropriate format for you, under most (not all) circumstances.

Comment: I'm on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my File was corrupted, I tested with another file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

VLC media player on Windows does a a very good job of detecting audio/video codecs.  If you running a *Nix system, then file extensions are not needed, these systems read the file header to determine the file type.

Have you tried to open the file with a text editor, to see if there are any hints to the file type in the first few lines of the file?

Comment: Why is everybody going on about file extensions and \*Nix? :/ If VLC did require extensions, it would require them everywhere. But since it is able to detect the file type itself, it uses that ability everywhere, *even on Windows*.

Comment: vlc player is great and i use it, but this kindda videos are more complicated than usual videos.

Comment: @Brainiac How so?

Comment: I did some research and found out this videos are encoded for preventing unauthorized viewing, so it needs special apps.

Comment: @Brainiac That's exactly I did not suggest using vlc.